# how to add Map contents to Multimap?

Tags: java, guava

```
Map<String,String> map1= new HashMap<String, String>(){{
            put("no1","123"); put("no2","5434"); put("no5","234");}};        

Map<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>(){{
            put("no1","523"); put("no2","234"); put("no3","234");}};


Multimap<String, String> totalMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

`totalMap.putAll()` supports only Multimap. How Can I put all map1 and map2 to the multimap ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Multimaps.forMap(Map<K,V>)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#forMap%28java.util.Map%29) to get a `Multimap` view of your map, then add that to the `totalMap`, e.g.:

```
totalMap.putAll(Multimaps.forMap(map1));
```